# How to capture Airflow Exception in a variable?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm trying to capture Airflow exception in a variable, whenever any task fails. It should be like, if there are A,B,C tasks so as soon as task B fails the exception string/message should be assigned to any variable.

The value of that variable should be the highlighted one in the image attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmD19.png)

Answer (score 0):

Either on success, failure, SLA miss or on retry, there are callbacks in the Airflow for this (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.2/logging-monitoring/callbacks.html)

Below is source code from Airflow site that might help you to understand this concept

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator


def task_failure_alert(context):
    print(f"Task has failed, task_instance_key_str: {context['task_instance_key_str']}")


def dag_success_alert(context):
    print(f"DAG has succeeded, run_id: {context['run_id']}")


with DAG(
    dag_id="example_callback",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
    catchup=False,
    on_success_callback=None,
    on_failure_callback=task_failure_alert,
    tags=["example"],
) as dag:

    task1 = DummyOperator(task_id="task1")
    task2 = DummyOperator(task_id="task2")
    task3 = DummyOperator(task_id="task3", on_success_callback=dag_success_alert)
    task1 >> task2 >> task3
```